# Render Chart on second template by clicking icon on the first template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have been working on a mobile application, where I use chart JS. I am stucked at one place where I need to draw chart by clicking on a icon.

The problem is, the icon is at template1.html and the chart should be drawn at template2.html. I am using angularJS. Therefore, every chart has its controller.

Therefore, all the code for the chart is at template2Controller. The question arrises, how to I draw the chart at template2.html by clicking an icon at template1.html.

**template1.html**

`<button class="" ng-click="daily()">
</button>`

**template2.html**

`<div id="dailyTab" class="chart" >
                        <canvas id="dailyChart" ></canvas>
                     </div>`

**template2Controller**

```
$scope.daily = function() {
    $http.get('jsonAPIURL'
).success(function(response) {

       var dailyCoffee = [];
      angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
        dailyCoffee.push(value.Currency);
      });

      var daily = {
        labels: ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23'],
        datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: "rgb(3,191,179)",
          data: dailyCoffee
        }]
      };
      var ctx = document.getElementById('dailyChart').getContext('2d');

      var chartDaily = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: daily,
         options: {
            responsive: true
              }
      });

    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there any relation between the controllers ? Are they parent/child ? You could use `AngularJs` events (`$emit, $broadcast`) if so.

If not, you might want to use a common parent ancestor, (if there isn't any, you can use rootScope`) to fire an event when clicking, and using $scope.$on to listen that event and draw the chart. Something like

**Template1 HTML**

```
ng-click="drawChart()"
```

**Template1 Controller**

```
$scope.drawChart = function(){
      // $root scope must be injected in the controller. Use the name you prefer
      $rootScope.$broadcast('draw-custom-chart');
};
```

**Template2Controller**

```
$scope.$on('draw-custom-chart', function($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.daily();
});
```

A better aproach, I believe, anyway is to move the `daily()` function into a service, and inject into the **Template1Controller** and call it from there. If you also need it in the **Template2Controller**, you can inject it there as well.

Comment: But it does not render the chart on template2.html? I have the chart id sent under <canvas id="dailyChart" ></canvas> in template2.html.

Comment: the code with events should  render in template2.html. If not, I believe it might be something wrong with your code that renders, but if you use debugger you'll see that the code in controller two is being called

Comment: Thank you! you fixed my problem! :)